# How to preview a delete_all or destroy_all query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

You know the drill: some invalid data pops up in the production database and you have to get rid of it. You fire up your Rails console on the production server and type in the query:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'baz').all
```

You review the returned data and it's what you need to remove. Then you type:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'baz').destroy_all
```

And your heart stops for a second. You just want to see the query before it runs.

Is there any way to do that in Rails? I'm looking for a method similar to

```
Foo.where(bar: 'baz').to_sql
```

but the one that will return the **DELETE** query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, you could run the console in sandbox mode and run the delete query to see the sql. The changes would just be rolled back on exit.

Comment: I suppose this doesn't really answer your question though, if you are really looking for a "to_sql"-like command.

Comment: I completely forgot about the sandbox mode! It's not exactly what I was looking for but it does exactly what I needed it to do. Especially considering that what I was looking for is impossible :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `destroy_all` does not run a single SQL query. It iterates through a hash of objects, instantiates them, runs their callbacks, and then calls that object's `destroy` method. Rails has no built-in way of producing an array of these queries.

Cdesroisiers is right that you can test the query in sandbox mode, but the real problem is that you're second-guessing your decision to run `delete_all`, even though you've verified whatever data is being targeted.

Consider using an ActiveRecord versioning gem like [PaperTrail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) if you're not willing to trust ActiveRecord to properly delete objects.

Comment: What is the justification behind not implementing `delete_all` as a batch operation I thought it is much cheaper to do it in a batch rather than making serious of round trip to the database.

Comment: delete_all is a batch operation. destroy_all does them one by one. delete_all exists because it is faster, destroy_all can be useful because it will fire before/after destroy callbacks.

Comment: PaperTrail is great for use in the app, but I just needed to get rid of some redundant data. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

the destroy_all method is the same as doing:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'baz').each { |object| object.destroy }
```

So the sql becomes

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo.id = your_objects_id_attribute
```

From docs:

```
  def destroy_all(conditions = nil)
    find(:all, :conditions => conditions).each { |object| object.destroy }
  end
```

Comment: I believe the generated SQL will consist of multiple DELETE queries - one per every object found.